# how to get the int score to view on my second activity

Tags: java, android, arrays, image

```
i am creating a quiz app that is multiple choice
```

in my first activity(MainActivity) is the  question(text) and choices

and in my second activity( QuizImage1)is the  question(image) and choices

how will i get the result of the score in main activity to view also in quizimage1

[image: mainactivity]

[image: second activity]

the second image is my error on quizimage1 because i did not copy the first activity score

i hope you understand what iam talking about

plss fix my codes

iam beginner in java

```
Main_Activity.java

    package com.example.ltoexam;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private com.example.ltoexam.QuestionLibrary nQuestionLibrary = new com.example.ltoexam.QuestionLibrary();

        public TextView nScoreView;
        private TextView nQuestionView;
        private Button nButtonChoice1;
        private Button nButtonChoice2;
        private Button nButtonChoice3;
        private Button quit;

        private String nAnswer;
        public int nScore = 0;
        private int nQuestionNumber = 0;




        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            nScoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
            nQuestionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
            nButtonChoice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice1);
            nButtonChoice2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice2);
            nButtonChoice3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice3);
            quit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.quit) ;

            updateQuestion();

            //Start of Button Listener for Button1
            nButtonChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //My logic for Button goes in here
                    if (nButtonChoice1.getText() == nAnswer){
                        nScore =nScore + 1;
                        updateScore(nScore);
                        updateQuestion();
                        //This line of code is optional
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "wrong the answer is " + nAnswer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        updateQuestion();
                    }
                }
            });

            //End of Button Listener for Button2


            //Start of Button Listener for Button2
            nButtonChoice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //My logic for Button goes in here
                    if (nButtonChoice2.getText() == nAnswer){
                        nScore =nScore + 1;
                        updateScore(nScore);
                        updateQuestion();
                        //This line of code is optional
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "wrong the answer is " + nAnswer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        updateQuestion();
                    }
                }
            });

                quit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    finish();
                    System.exit(0);

                }
            });



            //End of Button Listener for Button2


            //Start of Button Listener for Button3
            nButtonChoice3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //My logic for Button goes in here
                    if (nButtonChoice3.getText() == nAnswer){
                        nScore =nScore + 1;
                        updateScore(nScore);
                        updateQuestion();
                        //This line of code is optional
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "wrong the answer is " + nAnswer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        updateQuestion();
                    }
                }
            });

            //End of Button Listener for Button2




        }
        private void updateQuestion(){
            if(nQuestionNumber==7){

                openQuizImage1();}
            else {

                nQuestionView.setText(nQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(nQuestionNumber));
                nButtonChoice1.setText(nQuestionLibrary.getChoice1(nQuestionNumber));
                nButtonChoice2.setText(nQuestionLibrary.getChoice2(nQuestionNumber));
                nButtonChoice3.setText(nQuestionLibrary.getChoice3(nQuestionNumber));

                nAnswer = nQuestionLibrary.getCorrectAnswer(nQuestionNumber);
                nQuestionNumber++;
            }


            }



        public void updateScore(int point){
            nScoreView.setText("" + nScore);

        }
        public void openQuizImage1() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, QuizImage1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        }






    QuestionLibrary.java









    package com.example.ltoexam;

    public class QuestionLibrary {

        private String nQuestions [] = {
                "1.The three colors of the traffic lights are:",
                "2.Yellow triangular signs provide what kind of information",
                "3.Which of the following traffic signs are blue?",
                "4.Steady green light means",
                "5.A flashing yellow light at a road crossing signifies",
                "6.A solid white line on the right edge of the highway slopes in towards your left. This shows that",
                "7.You are in a No-Passing zone when the center of the road is marked by"

        };

        private String nChoices [] [] = {
                {"red, green and yellow", "red, green and blue", "yellow, green and blue"},
                {"warning", "hospital across", "speed limit"},
                {"regulatory signs", "information signs", "danger warning signs"},
                {"you must yield to all pedestrians and other motorists using the intersection", "go, it is safe to do so", "proceed cautiously through the intersection before the light changes to red."},
                {"Caution - slow down and proceed with caution", "Stop and stay until light stops flashing", "Wait for the green light"},
                {"there is an intersection joint ahead", "the road will get narrower", "you are approaching a construction area"},
                {"a broken yellow line","a broken white line","two solid yellow lines"}




        };

        private String nCorrectAnsers[] = {"red, green and yellow", "warning", "information signs", "go, it is safe to do so", "Caution - slow down and proceed with caution", "the road will get narrower", "two solid yellow lines"};

        public String getQuestion(int a) {
            String question = nQuestions[a];
            return question;
        }

        public String getChoice1(int a) {
            String choice0 = nChoices[a] [0];
            return choice0;
        }

        public String getChoice2(int a) {
            String choice1 = nChoices[a] [1];
            return choice1;
        }

        public String getChoice3(int a) {
            String choice2 = nChoices[a] [2];
            return choice2;
        }

        public String getCorrectAnswer(int a) {
            String answer = nCorrectAnsers[a];
            return answer;
        }


    }





    QuizImage1.java   (this is my second activity)











    package com.example.ltoexam;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class QuizImage1 extends AppCompatActivity {
        private Button but1;
        private Button but2;
        private Button but3;
        public TextView nScoreView;
        public int nScore;

        public TextView nScoreView() {
            return nScoreView;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_image1);
            but1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but1);
            but2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but2);
            but3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but3);
            nScoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);






            but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizImage1.this, "wrong the answer is Road goes left or right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    openQuizImage2();
                }
            });

            but2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizImage1.this, "wrong the answer is Road goes left or right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    openQuizImage2();
                }
            });

            but3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizImage1.this, "correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    openQuizImage2();
                    nScore =nScore + 1;
                    updateScore(nScore);
                }
            });




        }
        public void updateScore(int point){
            nScoreView.setText("" + nScore);}

        public void openQuizImage2(){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, QuizImage2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }




    activity_main.xml



    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Score"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:id="@+id/score_text"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="0"
                android:id="@+id/score"/>




        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="116dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/carter_one"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="Which thing is alive?"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/choice1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:background="#0091EA"
            android:fontFamily="@font/carter_one"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="bird"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/choice2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:background="#0091EA"
            android:fontFamily="@font/carter_one"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="door"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/choice3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:background="#0091EA"
            android:fontFamily="@font/carter_one"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="rock "
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/quit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:background="#871C1C"
            android:fontFamily="@font/carter_one"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="Quit"
            android:textColor="#fff" />


    </LinearLayout>









    activity_quiz_image1.xml


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".QuizImage1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Score"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:id="@+id/score_text"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="0"
                android:id="@+id/score"/>




        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/but1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="317dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="238dp"
            android:background="#0091EA"
            android:fontFamily="@font/carter_one"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="road ends"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/but2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="396dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="159dp"
            android:background="#0091EA"
            android:fontFamily="@font/carter_one"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="crossroads"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/but3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="476dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="79dp"
            android:background="#0091EA"
            android:fontFamily="@font/carter_one"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="Road goes left or right"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/quit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="549dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:background="#871C1C"
            android:fontFamily="@font/carter_one"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="Quit"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="249dp"
            android:layout_height="182dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/road_goes_left_right_road_traffic_sign"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="81dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="67dp" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

To transfer information from one activity to another, use the following :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityNext.class);
intent.putExtra("NSCORE_KEY", nScore );
startActivity(intent);
```

And in another activity get :

```
int nScore = getIntent().getIntExtra("KEY",1);
```

Comment: it is not working because i didnt copy the nScore value

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

To send data through activities you have to use the same intent you use to navigate to the activity as below.

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, QuizImage1.class);
   intent.putExtra("keyScore",nScore);
   startActivity(intent);
```

In the second activity `QuizImage1.class` in `OnCreate` method add the following code

```
  int score = getIntent().getIntExtra("keyScore",1);
```

Please take a look at the [official tutorial from android developer website](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity)

Comment: what is the purpose of 1 in int score?